# Anchor link pushes content outside of container when using equal heights columns

Tags: html, css

So here's a fun little "feature". Did you know that if you're using an equal heights column layout and include anchor links, clicking one of those links will totally mess up your layout? In my case the content get's pushed out of the container instead of jumping down to the correct section and leaving my layout intact.

[Here's my example.](http://www.ostforsk.no/om-oss/ansatte/)
Try clicking one of the text links in the right sidebar.

So the markup goes something like this:

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#content {
  width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.main {
  width: 66.6666667%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  float: left;
}
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333333%;
  min-height: 80px;
  background: red;
  padding-bottom: 9999px;
  margin-bottom: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="main">
    
    <div id="firstanchor">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tu autem inter haec tantam multitudinem hominum interiectam non vides nec laetantium nec dolentium? In quibus doctissimi illi veteres inesse quiddam caeleste et divinum putaverunt. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Te ipsum, dignissimum maioribus tuis, voluptasne induxit, ut adolescentulus eriperes P. Quis est, qui non oderit libidinosam, protervam adolescentiam?</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="secondanchor">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Ita nemo beato beatior. Itaque si aut requietem natura non quaereret aut eam posset alia quadam ratione consequi. Maximas vero virtutes iacere omnis necesse est voluptate dominante. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Esse enim, nisi eris, non potes. Sed erat aequius Triarium aliquid de dissensione nostra iudicare. Itaque hic ipse iam pridem est reiectus;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a href="#secondanchor">Go to second anchor</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to get around this and still keep my equal heights columns?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use anchor tags and keep my equal heights layout without the content jumping out of the container after a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why you want to use this `paddings and margings -9999px`
But here is one solution with different aproach.

**First way:**

You just do this sidebar absolute since you set width rest columns on `%`.
I know it might not be what are you looking for but - it might also help :)

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#content {
  width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
.main {
  width: 66.6666667%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  float: left;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="main">
    
    <div id="firstanchor">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tu autem inter haec tantam multitudinem hominum interiectam non vides nec laetantium nec dolentium? In quibus doctissimi illi veteres inesse quiddam caeleste et divinum putaverunt. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Te ipsum, dignissimum maioribus tuis, voluptasne induxit, ut adolescentulus eriperes P. Quis est, qui non oderit libidinosam, protervam adolescentiam?</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="secondanchor">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Ita nemo beato beatior. Itaque si aut requietem natura non quaereret aut eam posset alia quadam ratione consequi. Maximas vero virtutes iacere omnis necesse est voluptate dominante. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Esse enim, nisi eris, non potes. Sed erat aequius Triarium aliquid de dissensione nostra iudicare. Itaque hic ipse iam pridem est reiectus;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a href="#secondanchor">Go to second anchor</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Second way:**

And second way - you way is.
I found solution the img pushed you content sidebar so you need to keep all inside `#main` while you have `#main` and `.sidebar` on `float: none;`

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#content {
  width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.main {
  width: 66.6666667%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  float: left;
}
.main img{
  max-width: 100%;
 }
.sidebar {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="main">
    
    <div id="firstanchor">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tu autem inter haec tantam multitudinem hominum interiectam non vides nec laetantium nec dolentium? In quibus doctissimi illi veteres inesse quiddam caeleste et divinum putaverunt. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Te ipsum, dignissimum maioribus tuis, voluptasne induxit, ut adolescentulus eriperes P. Quis est, qui non oderit libidinosam, protervam adolescentiam?</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="secondanchor">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Ita nemo beato beatior. Itaque si aut requietem natura non quaereret aut eam posset alia quadam ratione consequi. Maximas vero virtutes iacere omnis necesse est voluptate dominante. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Esse enim, nisi eris, non potes. Sed erat aequius Triarium aliquid de dissensione nostra iudicare. Itaque hic ipse iam pridem est reiectus;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <a href="#secondanchor">Go to second anchor</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this approach :)

Comment: I add second way to do it - your way with paddings and marging and position: relative sidebar

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you, solved with flexbox:

```css
html {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing:inherit;
    box-sizing:inherit;
}
#content {
    align-items:stretch;
    display:flex;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:350px; 
}
.main {
    background:gray;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    float:left;
    min-height:200px;
    width:66.6666667%;
}
.sidebar {
    align-items::stretch;
    background: red;
    display:flex;
    float:right;
    min-height:80px;
    width:33.3333333%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="main">
        <div id="firstanchor">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tu autem inter haec tantam multitudinem hominum interiectam non vides nec laetantium nec dolentium? In quibus doctissimi illi veteres inesse quiddam caeleste et divinum putaverunt. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Te ipsum, dignissimum maioribus tuis, voluptasne induxit, ut adolescentulus eriperes P. Quis est, qui non oderit libidinosam, protervam adolescentiam?</p>
        </div>
        <div id="secondanchor">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150"/>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Ita nemo beato beatior. Itaque si aut requietem natura non quaereret aut eam posset alia quadam ratione consequi. Maximas vero virtutes iacere omnis necesse est voluptate dominante. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Esse enim, nisi eris, non potes. Sed erat aequius Triarium aliquid de dissensione nostra iudicare. Itaque hic ipse iam pridem est reiectus;</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <a href="#secondanchor">Go to second anchor</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @sebastianbrosch. This'll work, but unfortunately I can't use flexbox on this site. There's too much of a percentage of users using IE8/IE9 :/

Comment: Yes only available since IE10. It is a modern solution :)